Polars: series to column broadcast
This code used to work with polars < 1:
df.with_columns(pl.Series('k_list', [0, 1])).explode('k_list')

But now I have this error:
Séries k_list, length 2 doesn't match the dataframe height of ...
What is the proper way to add a series forn each row of a column?

df.with_columns(k_list=[0, 1]).explode("k_list")? if not, what is the expected output?

Please provide a runnable example along with the expected output.

You can pass a plain list with a name as kwargs:
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]}).with_columns(k_list=[0, 1]).explode("k_list")

print(df)

Output:
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ k_list │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0      │
│ 1   ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 0      │
│ 2   ┆ 1      │
│ 3   ┆ 0      │
│ 3   ┆ 1      │
└─────┴────────┘


Alternatively, if the name is not a valid Python identifier:
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
    .with_columns(pl.lit([0, 1]).alias("k_list"))
    .explode("k_list")
)

(same output)
